# Which Thread resume the method execution after await in Asp.net Web application

Tags: c#, multithreading

I read some articles about this question but i need some one clarify this for me,

```
public async Task<Person> Get()
{
   //some code 

    var result= await AsyncFunction();

    return result;
}
```

about above codes which i understand is when the code execution hit the `await` the current thread go to thread pool and When the method is ready to continue, any thread may choose from thread pool to continue method execution. is it true or not? the thread before `await` is same to after 'await' or not?

if i use `ConfigureAwait(false)` it cause to choose different thread for execution code? or it's not related to thread jump?

Comment: A proper answer to this question may be quite complex and involve lots of moving parts. May I ask *why* you ask this question? Does it matter if it's the same thread or not?

Comment: It depends if there is a SynchronisationContext (which WinForms, WPF and I think ASP.NET have, but a Console application usually doesn't). In this case, execution is usually resumed on the thread which called the await. If you use `ConfigureAwait(false)` execution is resumed on any free ThreadPool thread. The exact details depend on the implantation of the SynchronisationContext.

Comment: @ckuri in `.Net` context is RequestContext, but in `.NetCore` we don't have context anymore, please if you confident ur comment is true please post it as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend reading my [`async` intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

> When the method is ready to continue, any thread may choose from thread pool to continue method execution. is it true or not? the thread before await is same to after 'await' or not?

In ASP.NET, yes, that is true. Any available thread pool thread may resume execution of that method after the `await`.

> if i use ConfigureAwait(false) it cause to choose different thread for execution code? or it's not related to thread jump?

What actually happens is that the `await` by default will capture its current "context". On ASP.NET Core, there is no context to capture, so `await` uses the thread pool context. On ASP.NET pre-Core, there is a `SynchronizationContext.Current` value that is captured and used to resume executing the method. The ASP.NET (pre-Core) `SynchronizationContext` may use any thread pool thread; it's just there to ensure some things get copied over, most notably `HttpContext.Current`.

If you use `ConfigureAwait(false)`, then that is telling the `await` to *not* capture the current context. On ASP.NET Core, this has no effect because there's no context to capture anyway. On ASP.NET pre-Core, this will cause the method to resume executing on a thread pool thread but *not* use the `SynchronizationContext`, so `HttpContext.Current` is not available after the `await`.

Comment: Thanks for ur answering, after `await` Any available thread pool thread may resume execution of that method and it is not related to  `ConfigureAwait(false)`?

Comment: That is correct for ASP.NET, because the ASP.NET pre-Core context uses any available thread pool thread.